# AIX LIBPATH and STICKY BIT Set

Tags: aix

I have executable which runs fine in normal way. It loads a shared library. and I setting LIBPATH before launching that exe.
Now If I change the permission of the exe to owned by root and set sticky bit, then it fails to load the shared library.
If I create link in /usr/lib to the shared library everything works fine.

Any reason and solution for this problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a security feature - `LIBPATH` from your user environment is not used when running something with the sticky bit set. If it allowed you to use a user-set `LIBPATH` on an executable with suid set on it, someone could load a malicious library to compromise the system.

Also note that this security feature exists in Linux systems as well - `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` from a user's environment will be ignored when running a sticky-bit executable.

**Possible Solutions**

1 - One solution is to grant a user `sudo` privilege to execute that command, in which case you could do something like...

`sudo LIBPATH="..." executable`

2 - Another solution is to create a shell script that sets `LIBPATH` and then executes the executable, and set the sticky bit on your shell script, like this...

```
#/bin/sh

LIBPATH="/whatever/path" /path/to/executable
```

Comment: Is there any work-around or option which can enable me to get this work.